# How to inject an object passed to the BaseActivity, instantiating it with reflection (or any other way if possible)

Tags: java, android, components, code-injection, dagger

I have a BaseActivity, in which I am trying to retrieve the instance of a subclass in order to inject it with dagger.

I've been trying to figure out a way to not check manually the object passed on is an instance of every single Activity, but if there is a more optimal way of doing it.

F.i., if the component is as such:

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public class AppComponent {

   public void inject(FooActivity fooActivity);
   public void inject(BarActivity barActivity);
   public void inject(…);

}
```

Each activity extends BaseActivity and we have something like:

**FooActivity**

```
public class FooActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.inject(this);       
    }
}
```

Last, the issue comes when handling the BaseActivity.

**BaseActivity**

*current implementation*

```
...
 public void inject(FooActivity fooActivity) {
     DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(fooActivity)
 }

 public void inject(BarActivity barActivity) {
     DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(barActivity)
 }
...
```

However, I am looking for a more optimal way that reduces boilerplate, so I have been thinking something like the following:

**BaseActivity**

```
... 
 public void inject(Object activity) {
 // retrieve the instance of the activity
 // if possible and handle it so then we can: 
     DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(activity)
 }
...
```

But since I am required to find its instance, instead of having a series of if statements with `instanceof`, which I will need to update for every new activity, is there a way to handle it in a more automated way?

Comment: You could try to use AndroidInjection for this, because it exactly handles the use case --> injecting once in base class. Documentation here: https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html

Comment: Both of your `BaseActivity` implementations are wrong, that they should not create a new `AppComponent` every time. All those `inject(activity)` should use the same instance of `AppComponent`, otherwise different `AppComponent` instances can provide different instances of scoped (or `@Singleton`) dependencies. `dagger.android` solve this by building `AppComponent` once during `Application.onCreate` and effectively storing that instance in a field of the `Application`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! Usually I do have the local component interfaces in a class that extends Application and is declared within the manifest, and static methods within the same class that return them, declaring them on onCreate. I'm not sure if it's a good idea having them static (any insights on that?) or if makes the app less memory efficient, but it makes it easier to handle. Still, I'm not sure how to resolve the main issue I've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @mlyko! I'm checking (and trying to figure) it out.